# How to know from ListChangeListener.Change about which elements were removed?

Tags: java, javafx, observablelist

[`ObservableList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html) is ordered by nature and most access and reportings are index-based. But suddenly, when reporting about removements, they switched to value-based approach.

Why?

I have second list, which is carrying additional information for ObservableList and want to keep it in sync with ObservableList. I can track permutations, updatings and additions, but I can't track removements.

Why?

How to know the indices of removed elements from ObservableList? Is it possible?

JavaFX 8 doc is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html

**UPDATE**

Suppose I have `ObservableList`, which is containing 5 consequent identical values, for example, strings "person", "person", "person", "person", "person". Now I remove 3 last persons. How can I know that namely last 3 persons removed, if [`getRemoved()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html#getRemoved--) will show me just three values?

Answer (score 1):

I found that on delete, the method [`getFrom()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html#getFrom--) contains the starting index of deletion, and the method `getRemovedSize()` gives the number of deleted elements from that index. This information is enough to modify synched list.

Comment: What if you call removeAll(o) method on the observed list? Does your index-based approach still work?